# How to put rows from Excel into an ArrayList in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

The following code for reading the existing Excel file in java.

I want to get likely `[[a, b], [b, c, d], [a, c, d, e], [a, d, e], [a, b, c], [a, b, c, d], [a], [a, b, c], [a, b, d], [b, c, e]]...`, where `[a, b]` referred to one row in excel file. Please help me.

```
public class Excel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        List<Set<String>> itemsetList = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("bc_dataset.csv"));
        scanner.next();
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String str = scanner.next();
            itemsetList.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(str.split(","))));
            System.out.println(itemsetList);
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code?  The logic basically looks correct to me.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried and where you are stuck so the community can help you.

Comment: Do you have any exceptions thrown from your code? If not, what is working wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as following:

```
public class Excel {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
       List<Set<String>> itemsetList = new ArrayList<>();
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("bc_dataset.csv"));
       while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
           String str = scanner.nextLine();
           itemsetList.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(str.split(","))));
       }
       System.out.println(itemsetList);
       scanner.close();
   }
}
```